# GitHub API - how to get "amount of issues" to Google Sheets from private GitHub repo?

Tags: github, google-apps-script, google-sheets, github-api

I'm trying to come to grips with the GitHub API. I've gotten a detailed list of issues from the API, by doing this:

```
function myFunction() { var url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/repo/subrepo/issues';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
Logger.log(response);
}
```

but that just goes the console log - and does not seem to enable me to see how many issues there are. Is there a GitHub API method of getting the "total amount of open issues" or "closed issues"?

I'm ideally hoping to get data into a Google Sheet and feed it into Geckoboard, but first I gotta know I can actually get the required data into the log, then I can I guess start working on how to get it onto a sheet.

**PS** one specific detail: the repo is private - and the search-issues does not seem capable of accessing a *?access_token=mytoken*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the search feature of the GitHub API to get the issues you want. For example to find the issues from your "repo/subrepo" that are open you can use - **`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:repo/subrepo+state:open`**.

**NOTE** If your repo is private, you will need to [create an access_token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) and supply it in your query, like this:
**`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:repo/subrepo+state:open&access_token=yourToken`**.

In regular queries, **?access_token=yourToken** will work, but in a search such as this *the syntax must be* **&access_token=yourToken**

In the JSON response the field 'total_count' gives you the number of issues found in the search. Refer: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/

Comment: Poonacha, I'm now receiving this:
The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them - could you use something other than :  to separate stuff? is repo:repo like name_of_repo:name_of_repo or..?

Comment: The thing is that the repo is private - a public repo will work perfectly fine at least on the browser-level, but not necessarily on Google Apps Script Editor.

Comment: Oh.. then, do you want to find out a way to authenticate your URL request? i.e pass your authentication details (login and password) to UrlFetchApp.

Comment: yeah feels weird that ?access_token that works for other GETs from the api, does not function for this search thing :/

Comment: oh sorry.. i use python to access GitHub API and it has quite straight forward authentication. i.e. 'GitHubAPI_Results = requests.get(url, auth=('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))'. The only problem i face is that search requests have have a low rate limit (only 30 per hr), so I can not run too many searches at a time.

Comment: turns out all I needed to do was change ?access_token to &access_token and the data came through alright. now I can go back to trying to write it to google sheets.

Comment: @Michelle i'm not sure how to extract 'total_count' out of the JSON and write it to google sheets?

Answer (score 1):

just for people like me landed here from Google trying to get Issues amount for public repository:

For PUBLIC repositories or when you configured access token,
you can get amount of issues using formulas:

Open issues:

```
=IMPORTXML($F2, "//span[text()='Issues']/following-sibling::span[@class='Counter']/text()")
```

Closed solved issues:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE( INDEX(IMPORTXML($F2&"/issues", "//a[contains(@href, 'is%3Aclosed')]/text()"), 2, 1)  , ",", ""), "\d+"))
```

where F2 consists URL like:
https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore or
https://github.com/sulu/sulu