# Get Github repo data after authenticating with OAuth and Auth0

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, github-api, auth0

What i want to do, is to get private repo datas (issues amount) from a small application.

Since I don't want to expose my [personal github access_token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) in the request I searched another solution which I think is OAuth.

So i setted up an OAuth following [these](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/github) and [these](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs) steps.

And setted the permissions in [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) in the social github settings to `repo` (grants read/write access for repos).

Until now everything works fine, I'm able to authenticate with my github account.

But now I don't know which `token` I have to use for my `request` to the github `API`.

Here is the relevant code I have so far:

```
const  handleAuthentication = () => {
  webAuth.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
      window.location.hash = '';
      setSession(authResult);

      //here the call to the relevant function
      getIssues('my-element', /*here i should pass the correct token*/); //tryed all tokens i found in authResult

    } else if (err) {
      alert(
        `Error: ${err.error} . Check the console for further details.`
      );
    }
  });
}

const getIssues = (element, token) => {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', `https://api.github.com/repos/my_organization/element-${element}/issues?access_token=${token}`, true);

  request.onload = () => {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      //use the data
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('connection error: ', e)
  };

  request.send();
}
```

But this results to a 401 (Unauthorized) response.

I didn't use `XMLHttpRequests` a lot and I'm sure, that I'm missing something fundamental here.

And now i'm not even sure if oAuth is the correct way to achieve what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Meanwhile I did some more research and found out ([here](https://community.auth0.com/questions/1015/get-github-token-for-user)), that there are some steps missing to get the correct user access_token for connecting to the github api.

I'll try to complete these steps and will post an answer if it works.

Would still appreciate a clear answer if somebody knows how to do it exactly.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the syntax used to create the URL. There was a  similar issue in this line -  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277612/github-api-how-to-get-amount-of-issues-to-google-sheets-from-private-github/45280313#45280313)

Comment: @Poonacha using the same syntax with my personal access_token works, so I don't think, that this is the issue

Answer (score 1):

To get list of issues of a repo, call this API endpoint:

`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repository}/issues`

Where the `${owner}` is the organization name (**NOT** your github username), and `${repo}` is the repo that you want to list the issues.

For reference, the documentation is here: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository. However like a lot OAuth endpoint documentation, this is cryptic, thus requires hours of tinkering.

There is a live working code snippet so that you can see the sample code, test and tweak it: https://jsfiddle.net/son74dj2/

The code snippet explanation follows.

It uses https://oauth.io service and its SDK (the OAuth class in the code below), which is not required. However OAuth.io enables you to implement OAuth flow with just front-end, e.g., Javascript, so the live working code snippet can be self-contained in a jsfiddle that can be easily shared, tweaked, tested and even just cut-and-pasted on your website.

```
$('#github-button').on('click', function() {

    // Initialize with your OAuth.io app public key
    OAuth.initialize('YOUR OAUTH.IO PUBLIC KEY');

    // Use popup for oauth
    OAuth.popup('github').then(provider => {

        const repository = 'YOUR REPOSITORY';

        const owner = 'REPOSITORY OWNER';

        provider.get(`/repos/${owner}/${repository}/issues`).then(data => {
            alert('Now you could see list of issues in the console!')
            console.log('Issue list:', data);
        })
    });
})
```

Hope this is useful to help you understand and test the endpoint without spending hours figuring out the documentation, and tinkering with the url and parameters.

**NOTE**: You need to have access to the repo, which the repo owner needs to grant you. See the original article for screenshot details: https://tome.oauth.io/providers/github/get-repository-issue-list